# What kind of plot will be helpful for total count group data ( data grouped by month and year )?

Tags: regression, dataset, data-mining, visualization, plotting

I have a group data frame like this :

```
group_by_region_year_month=train_data.groupby(['Region Name (GO)','Year','Month'],as_index=False)
    
    region_sum=group_by_region_year_month.agg({"AMV": "sum"})
```

Here, `AMV` is my target variable in regression (this is the count of total vehicles).

I have data for each day from 2000-3-17 to 2017-10-11.

I want to show the variation of the count for each year and each month for each Region.

How best can I plot it?

I tried using `seaborn.FacetGrid` in this way:

`# g=sns.FacetGrid(row="Region Name (GO)", col="AMV", data=region_sum)`

But it is taking too much time.

Is there any better alternative(s)?

## Edit 1

I tried this :

```
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(50,30)})

ax=sns.barplot(x='Region Name (GO)', y='AMV', hue='Year', data=train_data)
ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=90)
```

which gave me a very clumsy plot :
[image: Total vehicle count]

I did not use `countplot` as countplot would give me a count of rows. But, I want the sum of all values in a group.

Can I represent it in any better way?

Answer (score 1):

If you like using Seaborn to construct your plots, `sns.countplot` is probably the best for plotting data where you want to show the differences in value counts.

You can find the link to the documentation page [here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html) which might be helpful for you to construct it in the  particular way you want.

As an example, here is a version of a "multiple" count plot like you suggest. (directly from the Seaborn Documentation page)

[image]